# .net core memory dump in production

Tags: asp.net-core, memory

I have an asp.net core 3.1 application running under IIS. It's had a fairly sudden increase in memory and I'd like to do a memory dump.

Is there a safe production process to follow? Its a load balanced environment to it would be straight forward enough to add and remove from the load balancer. There's no session state but we do use caching.